# Calendar (date-picker) control for mobile devices in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mobile, calendar, datepicker, mobile-website

I'm looking for a calendar control ([AKA](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AKA) date-picker) that works on mobile devices. The problem is most devices are without JavaScript, or with poor JavaScript support.

[ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET)'s built-in control uses JavaScript to do post-backs. ASP.NET has a mobile calendar control, but it isn't fully localizable (on low-end devices where it displays a step-by-step date picker, its buttons are always in English).

I am thinking of overriding the built-in calendar control to replace the JavaScript post-back directly with parameterized links.

My *compound* question is -

Is there a good JavaScript-less calendar control, of a way to get rid of JavaScript in ASP.NET's built-in control, or of a way to localize ASP.NET's mobile calendar control?

If all of the above doesn't exist, is replacing the post-back with parameterized links a good way to go? What would other suggestions be?

Currently, I'm not concerned with formatting - the device I'm targeting displays the date-picker well. I'm concerned only with the small problem of getting it to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is building a custom calendar control.

For now, I used a table, but it will have to change when I want to support more devices. Since I'm targeting right-to-left languages, a table is already a pain.

@troelskn - I didn't go for `<select>` because they're not comfortable for a user using a mobile device, but thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate some dropdown (`<select>`) boxes and use them as a simple datepicker. You'll need to do some server side validation though, since no JavaScript would mean that the user could pick an invalid date (for example, 31st of Feb).

Comment: Thanks, but <select> results in a ComboBox, which I find uncomfortable on mobile devices.

Comment: Really? They are fairly standard gui components, so I would expect them to work everywhere. They certainly do on my iPhone. But then I haven't really made much interface aimed at mobile devices, so you probably know better than me.

Comment: They *work*, but they aren't very comfortable, at least on the Nokia-s I tested.